# How to surround arrays with one array?

Tags: php

So I need to surround few arrays with just one array. Lets call few arrays with a,b,c and main array - d.
I am creating a,b,c with foreach. And I need somehow place arrays like this:
d = [a, b, c].
Here is actual code:

```
$newData[$name] = array(                  // $name = a,b and c while loop.
        'playerCount' => $plOnline,
        'maxPlayers' => $plMax,
        'online' => $status
    );
```

I tried array_push, merge, but nothing really does, what I want. Anybody can help me?

**One more important thing: arrays must be pushed with their keys!**

EDITED:
Current state:

```js
array(4) {

 ["hitech"]=> array(3) { ["playerCount"]=> int(27) ["maxPlayers"]=> int(50) ["online"]=> string(6) "online" } 
 ["electro"]=> array(3) { ["playerCount"]=> int(15) ["maxPlayers"]=> int(100) ["online"]=> string(6) "online" } 
 ["atom"]=> array(3) { ["playerCount"]=> int(51) ["maxPlayers"]=> int(100) ["online"]=> string(6) "online" }

}
```

Desired state:

```js
array(4) {
["servers"]=> array {

 ["hitech"]=> array(3) { ["playerCount"]=> int(27) ["maxPlayers"]=> int(50) ["online"]=> string(6) "online" } 
 ["electro"]=> array(3) { ["playerCount"]=> int(15) ["maxPlayers"]=> int(100) ["online"]=> string(6) "online" } 
 ["atom"]=> array(3) { ["playerCount"]=> int(51) ["maxPlayers"]=> int(100) ["online"]=> string(6) "online" }

 } 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what result you desire. Could you give an example of expected output vs. the output you get when using the functions that didn't work?

Comment: Why don't you post the `foreach` loop, and give sample data, and the required output for that sample. That way there cannot be a misunderstanding as to what you mean.

Comment: If after the loop you do `$newData = [$newData];` or `$newData = ["d" => $newData];`, does that give you the desired result?

Comment: @trincot Added desired and current states. Look above*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create the *surround* array with foreach loop, and then insert it in the `$newData`.

```
$d=[]; // your "surround" array
foreach(...){
    $d[$name]=array( // $name = a, b and c
        'playerCount' => $plOnline,
        'maxPlayers' => $plMax,
        'online' => $status
    );
}
$newData["servers"]=$d;
```